# Entity Framework Select column that contains two words in order

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

I have two text in a column:

```
1 - aaaaaaaWORD1aaaaaaaaaWORD2aaaaaa
2 - aaaaaaaWORD2aaaaaaaaaWORD1aaaaaa
```

When I want to search WORD1 and WORD2 in order I try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%WORD1%WORD2'
```

And It returns only one row with this order:

```
1- aaaaaaaWORD1aaaaaaaaaWORD2aaaaaa
```

How I do it in Entity Framework? I try to use contains clause but It returns two records

```
var query = _context.Table.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable()
                    .Where((ca.Message.ToLower().Contains("WORD1") &&
                            ca.Message.ToLower().Contains("WORD2")))
```

Comment: What database type are you targeting? For SqlServer you could use `EF.Functions.Like` exactly the same way as in SQL. There is no database agnostic function.

Comment: I'm using Postgresql and I've just founded the same solution. Many thanks

Comment: Yeah, my bad. `EF.Functions.Like` is provided by EF Core, thus is available (in theory) for all databases. Glad it helped anyway :)